# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. | Gatsby JS

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Hi got the warning that told me that each child in a list should have a unique key prop. My component have it, but the warning keep showing up.

I think it's cause i insert Component inside another Component, if someone can tell me how to fix it please ?

Here is my differents files :

Here is my query (index.js):

```
posts: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/posts/"}}, 
        limit: 5
        sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}) {
        edges {
            node {
              frontmatter {
                date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY", locale: "fr-FR")
                slug
                title
                excerpt
              }
              html
              id
            }
        }   
    }
```

My index.js :

```
const projects = data.projects.edges
<Projects projects={projects}/>
```

My projects.js

```
    return (
    <>
        {projects.map(project => (
            <Project key={project.id} project={project}/>
        ))}
    </>
)
```

My project.js

```
    return (
    <Col className="h-100" key={project.node.id} xs="12" md="6" lg="4">
        <div className="card p-5 h-100">
            <h3 className="text-center">{project.node.frontmatter.title}</h3>
            <div className="tags">
                {project.node.frontmatter.source && (
                    <a href={project.node.frontmatter.source} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Source</a>
                )}
                {project.node.frontmatter.demo && (
                    <a href={project.node.frontmatter.demo} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Démo</a>
                )}
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: project.node.html}}>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Col>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `projects` loop, `project.id` is `undefined` so the `key` is not valid (because it's not different in each iteration). Try using:

```
return (
<>
    {projects.map(project => (
        <Project key={project.node.id} project={project}/>
    ))}
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use like this way

```
return (
<>
    {projects.map((project,key) => (
        <Project key={key} project={project}/>
    ))}
</>
```

Comment: is not a good practice to use the `index` of the loop as a `key`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631413/react-index-as-key-is-this-a-good-practice-or-should-i-use-react-uuid